# execute multi query when I hit submit with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm just learning Mysql/PHP and I'm trying to execute a multi query using msqli. I have read through several tutorials, and tried to apply them, but I cannot get this working... hope someone can help me.

Dont mind my messy code, will clean later!!!

**Code :**

```html
else if (isset($_POST['btnSlaOpInGs'])) {
  $id=$_POST['id'];
  $uitgeleend=$_POST['uitgeleend'];
  $nr=$_POST['nr'];
  $model=$_POST['model'];
  $serienummer=$_POST['serienummer'];
  $capaciteit=$_POST['capaciteit'];
  $uptodate=$_POST['uptodate'];
  $persoon=$_POST['persoon'];
  $datumuitgeleend=$_POST['datumuitgeleend'];
  $datumretour=$_POST['datumretour'];
  $opmerking=$_POST['opmerking'];
  $sql="UPDATE ipads SET nr='$nr', model='$model', serienummer='$serienummer', capaciteit='$capaciteit', uptodate='$uptodate', persoon='$persoon', datumuitgeleend='$datumuitgeleend', datumretour='$datumretour', opmerking='$opmerking' WHERE id='$id';";
  $sql.="INSERT INTO geschiedenis (SELECT * FROM ipads WHERE id='$id');";
  $sql.="UPDATE ipads SET uitgeleend='Nee', persoon='', datumuitgeleend='', datumretour='', opmerking='' WHERE id='$id';";
  mysqli_multi_query($db, $sql);
  header("location:index.php");
}
```

Form :

```html
<form id="gegevensForm" class="col-xs-4" form method="POST" action="ipad-edit.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id?>">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Uitgeleend</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="uitgeleend"/>
   <option value="Ja" <?php if($uitgeleend == "Ja") echo "selected";?>>Ja</option>
   <option value="Nee" <?php if($uitgeleend== "Nee") echo "selected";?>>Nee</option>
  </select>
 </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nr</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nr" value="<?php echo $nr ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Model</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="model" value="<?php echo $model ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Serienummer</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="serienummer" value="<?php echo $serienummer ?>" />
    </div>
    
 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Capaciteit</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="capaciteit" value="<?php echo $capaciteit ?>" />
    </div>
   
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Up-to-Date</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="uptodate"/>
   <option value="Ja" <?php if($uptodate == "Ja") echo "selected";?>>Ja</option>
   <option value="Nee" <?php if($uptodate == "Nee") echo "selected";?>>Nee</option>
  </select>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Persoon</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="persoon" value="<?php echo $persoon ?>" />
    </div>
 
 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Datum uitgeleend</label>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control" name="datumuitgeleend" value="<?php echo $datumuitgeleend ?>" />
    </div>
 
 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Datum retour</label>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="form-control" name="datumretour" value="<?php echo $datumretour ?>" />
    </div>
 
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Opmerking</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="opmerking" /><?php echo $opmerking ?></textarea>
 </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="btnSlaOp" input type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Opslaan</button>
 
    <a href="overzicht-ipads.php"><input type="button" name="btnCancel" value="Annuleer" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></a>
 
 <button class="btn btn-primary pull-middle" name="btnSlaOpInGs" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Opslaan & Archiveren</button>
 
    <?php
  include('../includes/get_footer.php');
 ?>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to separate multiple query by `;`

Comment: If you want to execute multiple query then multiple queries are concatenated by a semicolon.

Comment: When you're cleaning the code later, make sure you test cases where the form data includes apostrophes and semi-colons.

Comment: The semi column look perfect . Just One thing use prepare statement http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Saty how do I apply this in my code? Sorry for asking ...

Comment: Check the link above provided by me. Learn it and apply it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **DO NOT USE multi_query.** this function has a very special purpose that doesn't fit for your case. run your queries through separate calls.
2. Use prepared statements.
3. Use PDO, especially if you are only learning PHP.

The code should be

```
$sql="UPDATE ipads SET nr=?, model=?, serienummer=?, capaciteit=?, uptodate=?, persoon=?, datumuitgeleend=?, datumretour=?, opmerking=? WHERE id=?";
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([$nr,$model,$serienummer,$capaciteit,$uptodate,$persoon,$datumuitgeleend,$datumretour,$opmerking,$id]);

$sql="INSERT INTO geschiedenis (SELECT * FROM ipads WHERE id=?)";
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([$id]);

$sql ="UPDATE ipads SET uitgeleend='Nee', persoon='', datumuitgeleend='', datumretour='', opmerking='' WHERE id=?";
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([$id]);
```

though I don't quite understand what all this stuff is intended to do. All these settings and resettings of same values looks like a total mess.